# How to set DateTimePicker to certain time and keep the current date?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

When button is clicked, I want to set the `DateTimePicker` to show Date and Time as following:

`date` = current date.

`time` = `10:30:00`.

The following code changes both date and time BUT does not keep current date:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 10, 30, 0);
}
```

What I want is : how to customize the time to `10:30:00` and keep the current date (today's date)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime.Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) with [`DateTime.AddHours`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx) for that.

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10.5);
```

This property sets to today's date, with the time component is midnight. Adding `10.5` hours will return current date as date with `10:30` as time.

Comment: @ Soner Gönül . your code is correct but I am sorry I meant 10:30:00 not 10:00:00 , I updated the question. can you please update your answer. thank you

Comment: @naouf Then you need to add `10.5` instead of `10` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 10, 30, 0);
```

If it is only for display purpose use DateTimePicker's properties `Format = 'Custom'` and `CustomFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00'` . This will display current date and current hour (the control's value remains curent datetime).

Comment: This question is not about _formatting_. It is about choosing the right `DateTime`.

Comment: I still don't understand the question exactly. For choosing the DateTime I wrote the second example @Soner.

Comment: "What I want is : how to customize the time to 10:30:00 and keep the current date (today's date)?"

Comment: dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 10, 30, 0); I've replaced in my second example the DateTime.Now.Hour with 10 and 0 from Minutes with 30. Sorry if it is not still what you need. The date is kept, the time is what you set manually.

Comment: @Soner Gönül I changed the second statement so you can remove the downvote

Comment: @Soner Gönül sorry for that. Someone was mean to me than :)